# Hash Merge Error in SAS

Tags: hash, merge, sas, hashtable

I am trying to create a hash merge between two tables, `output.hicno_xwalk`, and `papi_claim_01`. Before, I had been doing a normal match-merge using proc sorts and a data step. Here is the original code:

```
proc sort data = output.hicno_xwalk;
by HICNUMBER Plan_Type;
run;

proc sort data = papi_claim_01;
by HICNUMBER Plan_Type;
run;

data papi_claim_01a;
merge output.hicno_xwalk (in=a)
  papi_claim_01 (in=b);
by HICNUMBER Plan_Type;
if (b);
run;
```

Now, I am using this:

```
data hash_merge (drop = rc);
set output.hicno_xwalk point = _n_;
if 0 then set output.hicno_xwalk papi_claim_01; *load properties;
declare hash merge(dataset:'output.hicno_xwalk'); 
merge.definekey (HIC); *define variable to use as a key (no duplicates);
merge.definedata ('NEW_HIC','Plan_Type'); *Columns from the merge table to include;
merge.definedone(); *end hash;

do until (eof);
set papi_claim_01 end = eof;
if merge.find() = 0 then output;
end;
stop; *output records where HIC is found in both tables;

run;
```

However, I get an error in my log saying

> ERROR: Type mismatch for method parameter 1 at line 404 column 5.
>   ERROR: Expecting Character type. ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object
>   failure.
>
> Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

What is the error trying to tell me, and how do I fix my code?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This may help: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/HASH-mistype-error/td-p/161946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key variable name must be quoted:

```
merge.definekey ('HIC')
```

On another note, I'm not sure what's the purpose of some code in your DATA step (like option `point` or `do` loop with `stop` or multiple `set`-statements for the same dataset), but unless you need it for some other reasons, not shown in your code snippet, just hash merge can be done much simpler:

```
data hash_merge;
  set papi_claim_01;
  if 0 then set output.hicno_xwalk;
  if _n_=1 then do; *to avoid re-creating hash-object every time;
    declare hash merge(dataset:'output.hicno_xwalk'); 
    merge.definekey ('HIC'); 
    merge.definedata ('NEW_HIC','Plan_Type');
    merge.definedone();
  end;

  if merge.find() = 0;

run;
```